# таймер запаздывает

Tags: flutter, dart

подскажите есть ли по этому коду альтернативный вариант, у меня такое чувство что таймер(или задержка) немного запаздывает когда вызывается этот метод раз за разом:

```
void cycle() {
    var a = data.duration *
        (data.position.length);
    play();
    Timer(Duration(milliseconds: (60000 / a).floor()), () {
      setState(() {
        cursor =
            operations.cursorMoveForward(cursor, data, _scrollController);
      });
      if (
          cursor.position == position.length - 1 || !onPlay) {
      } else {
        cycle();
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: А может попробовать через `do…while`, зачем рекурсию использовать?

Comment: я выяснил что во всем виноват `setState`, он просто не успевает обновлять состояние виджета, но мне нужно изменять состояние так как пользователь должен понимать где находиться курсор в данный момент

Comment: Там скорее виновата большая вложенность в stateful виджет... Попробуйте сделать курсор через оверлей.

Comment: а поможет ли это если пользователь без запуска цикла с помощью тапа или стрелок меняет положение курсора?

Comment: без `setState` все прекрасно работает и тап и цикл и стрелки вот только в интерфейсе ничего не происходит так как состояние не меняется, а вот с помощью `setState` все тормозит запаздывает, вложение может быть разной так как пользователь редактирует документ но не текстовый документ а специфический

Comment: Вам надо обновлять экран быстрее 16 мс. тогда, не будет тормозить.

Comment: https://medium.com/flutterdevs/draggable-and-drag-target-in-flutter-2513ea7c09f2